# is the word "lead" used correctly in the below sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Is that correct to use "lead" in the below sentence that I wrote? Should I use another verb like "cause" or "make" instead?

> when a user click on it, a couple lines of code, written by back-end developer, **execute that lead to download a file.**

Comment: You should tell us if you wrote that line or you saw it somewhere. The sentence as it stands is understandable but poorly composed and ungrammatical.

Comment: unfortunately I wrote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several grammatical errors in your sentence, and I cannot quite work out what your intention is in using the world "lead".

> When a user click**s** on it, a couple **of** lines of code, written by **a** back-end developer, download a file.

or

> cause it to download a file.

but I would say that it is the lines of code that download the file, so I would not use "cause".

"A couple lines" is grammatical in some varieties of English (not my own) but it is not standard.

I don't know what your purpose is in saying "written by a back-end developer": the only context I can think of where that would make sense is if this is actually talking about how the user interface is implemented: perhaps that is your point.